# Duplicate -tpl.c~ files when created a new project in Django (Atom Text Editor)

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I created a new project with

```
django-admin startproject basicform
```

And then created a new application

```
django-admin startapp basicapp
```

But, when i started my server,

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It made duplicated files, like this

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MTvpHf7pACsp9o_b129g5wPsKqwbbZDp

**Is this an ERROR?
Should i delete the files?**

I am working on django-1.11 and  Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Also, when i tried running the server, it worked fine.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1arjf3U8Mm8ggwLTbSk5Gc9bd_FDl5lJj

**EDIT**:
I have deleted the duplicate -tpl.c~ files and the project is working fine.

Comment: As shown in figure, it is working. What's the problem?

Comment: @Harsha Django project is working fine. But, only when i edit files like 'views.py', not 'views-tpl.c~.py'.

Comment: In which file you are changing? and can you show urls and views.py files?

Comment: @Harsha By editing those files, i meant deleting it. I've deleted all the duplicate files. 
Also, when i start a new project, it again creates duplicates. 

I am using ATOM TEXT EDITOR for my work.

Answer (score 0):

"~" is a common suffix for backup files created by an editor. It is safe to remove them if you don't need them, and you should be using a VCS to handle old revisions regardless.

Comment: I have deleted them for now. But, what if i don't want the editor to create?
How can i stop it to create backup files?